# Invalid Block type Multi store 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I have a multi site store with a third party payment system, Klarna.

The module works fine on one site, but on other stores, fails and generates the following error.

I have checked that the module output isn't disabled at the store level but am unsure how to proceed from here.

Any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ugyldig bloktype: Mage_Klarna_Block_Frame' in /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/Mage.php:594
Stack trace:
#0 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ugyldig bloktyp...')
#1 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('klarna/frame', Array)
#2 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('klarna/frame', 'klarna_form')
#3 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('klarna/frame', 'klarna_form')
#4 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(159): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
#10 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/httpd/tapetstore/tapetstore.se/index.php(88): Mage::run('tapetdk', 'store')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have copied template and layout folders and files of your module to other sites theme folders